How to configure Azure service bus queue and topic which have different namespace in same Spring Boot application?
I have a Spring Boot application in which I am reading messages from a Azure service bus queue. Now I need to write another listener which will read message from a topic. Here both queue and topics have different namespace so I am facing issues in merging the configuration for both in application.yml file.
I need to connect to 2 ServiceBus which have different namespace from single SpringBoot application.
I am using passwordless-enabled: true so not using connection string
One namespace is for a queue and another namespace is for topic.
pom.xml
<spring-cloud-azure.version>4.17.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>4.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>       

application.yml
spring:
  jms:
    listener:
      receive-timeout: 60000
    servicebus:
      namespace: topic-namespace
      passwordless-enabled: true
      pricing-tier: standard
      enabled: true
      topic-client-id: 5e78-4034-a948-44e819798c12
      topic-name: topic-name
      subscription-name: topic-cription-dev

---
spring:
  jms:
    listener:
      receive-timeout: 60000
    servicebus:
      namespace: queue-namespace
      passwordless-enabled: true
      topic-client-id: 4b41-9a94-67cc176e1f74
      pricing-tier: standard
      queue-name: queue-name
      enabled: true

spring.cloud.azure:
  credential:
    client-id: 4261-aa28-d150ffafe565
    client-secret: .So13hhZ1b3V
  profile:
    tenant-id: ef0-43ca-a603-a8a1e287fa9d

QueueListner
@JmsListener(destination = "${spring.jms.servicebus.queue-name}",  containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void receiveMessage(byte[] message) {
    log.info("Queue Message received: {}", new String(message));
    
}

TopicListner
@JmsListener(destination = "${spring.jms.servicebus.topic-name}",
        subscription = "${spring.jms.servicebus.subscription-name}",
        containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    log.info("Message received: {}", message);
}


While looking for its solution, I found this-
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/servicebus/spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder-servicebus/servicebus-multibinders
This example explains how we can bind to two Service Bus namespaces separately through a queue binder and a topic binder.
